# Sending $ajax via jQuery to C# codebehind not working

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am having unexplained behavior when I post from jquery using ajax to C#.

1) The main page is called not the method I am requesting in jQuery.

To work around this I simply put an if in the page load so that if a particular item is in the querystring it will trigger a series of commands. It does hit that if statement and runs the code perfectly fine. There are some methods that do things like change a color on the map. These never actually happen. I can set a label and it will pass right over it but the label remains unset.

2) strangely enough.... my page has a timer with a refresh on it. It refreshes the page and now the changes are processed.

Here is the way I am calling my method in jQUery:

```
 function mycmethod(param)
    {
        //alert(precinct);
        $.ajax({
            url: "myPage.aspx/someMethod",
            type: 'POST',
            data: "params=" + param,
            success: function iGotData(responseJSON) {

            //    alert("Worked");

            },
            error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                console.log("Error: " + errorThrown);
                console.log("Status: " + status);
                console.log(xhr);
                alert("Didnt work:" + errorThrown);

            },

            })
        };
```

It was originally set to async: true but that didn't make a difference.

The method its not calling on load is:

```
[WebMethod][ScriptMethod]
public Boolean someMethod(string param)
{

    setFeatures();
    GenerateMap();

    return true;
}
```

I doubt its relevant but I am calling a jquery call with over mouse over of a specific element. That jquery calls a function which calls a asmx web service that returns some jSON. I am calling the `mycmethod` after the JSON is returned.

Why is my UI elements not responding until the page refreshes. If not,  is there a way I can force a refresh like the timer does?

Comment: Not about answer: never use `async: false`. It's bad and deprecated.

Comment: I know... just trying anything :(

Answer (score 3):

[WebMethods] methods should be declared as static.

I've also found that you might need to specify the content type in your ajax call:

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

Also, your data option looks suspicious. Maybe you should append it to the url option:

```
url: "myPage.aspx/someMethod?params" + parm
```

or, more ideally, send it as either a JSON object or a JSON string:

```
data: {
    params: param
}
```

or

```
data: JSON.stringify({
    params: param
})
```

Comment: @logixologist, OK, please post some of your markup for us to see.

Comment: @logixologist I mean the HTML. I'd like to see how you bound the `mycmethod` function.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you're loading the page, then calling the server via ajax and expecting the server to change UI elements of the currently loaded page.

It doesn't work like that, unfortunately. Once you've served the page, the server itself cannot manipulate that page without doing a refresh/post back (or something along those lines).

If you want to update the UI without doing a refresh/post back you can have your WebMethod return HTML, and your jQuery `success` method can update the relevant controls.

Alternatively you could use jQuery's `.get()` to retrieve a fresh copy of the page via ajax, and update your current page like that. (although it's less efficient)

Comment: it's not really about updating the page again. I really need to trigger some c# methods. How can I force the page to post back.

Comment: So you're saying `someMethod` is never being called? If you look at your browsers debug tools, is the ajax request ever happening?

Comment: Yes it is... Its strange. The `myPage.aspx` is loading but not going into the `someMethod`. I verified using `Charles` that the call does successfully go and it breakpoints on the PageLoad if I put a stop their.

Comment: In the ajax request, try changing `data: "params=" + param,` to `data: "{'params': '" + param + "'}`. Additionally, add the following the parameter to the request `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"`. I'm wondering if maybe it wants the argument sent over as `json` and isn't recognizing it as just a raw string.

Comment: Thanks i'll have to look at it Monday when I get back to work. Thanks for your help.!